# Executing Swift code embedded into one line terminal command

Tags: swift, bash, terminal

I know there is the Swift REPL and the Xcode playgrounds, but I wonder whether there is an alternative to `ruby -e "<code>"` or `sh -c "<code>"` in Swift where the given one line code would be executed as the result of the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Swift version 5.8, you can now runs code directly from the command line with `swift -e`

```bash
bash-3.2$ swift --help | grep -e "-e "
  -e <value>              Executes a line of code provided on the command line
```

```bash
bash-3.2$ swift -e 'print("fofo")'
fofo
```

```bash
bash-3.2$ swift -e 'import Foundation ; var users = ["zoe", "joe", "albert", "james"] ; for user in users {  print(user) }'
zoe
joe
albert
james
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer starting with Swift 5.8.

Answer (score 7):

There isn't a direct equivalent (you can ask the `swift` command for its options with `swift --help` and see there's nothing like Ruby's `-e`).

*But there's a workaround.*

You can pass a Swift expression to the compiler direclty using `echo` and `|` (the "pipe") like this:

```
echo "print(42)" | swift
```

Result:

> Welcome to Apple Swift version 2.1.1 ("700.1.101.9 700.1.78"). Type :help for assistance.
>   42

I guess it's similar to the behavior you were looking for.

We notice that it always prints the introduction sentence, but there's a way to fix this, by adding `-` at the end of the command, like this:

```
echo "print(42)" | swift -
```

Result:

> 42

When using literal strings, escape the double quotes:

```
echo "print(\"hello\")" | swift -
```

Result:

> hello

You can execute any expression, even loops:

```
echo "for num in 1...5 { print(num) }" | swift -
```

Result:

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   5

etc.

It's still the REPL so it will give feedback about variables (omitting the `-` trick at the end), for example:

```
echo "let x = 42;print(x)" | swift
```

Result:

> Welcome to Apple Swift version 2.1.1 ("700.1.101.9 700.1.78"). Type :help for assistance.
>   42
>   x: Int = 42